# Scripts Linux - awk

Tags: awk

I have small problem. I need to explaint, what does awk.

I need to write a script that monitors the load on the system is overloaded (CPU, RAM) and writes message.

I have this:

```
if 
[[ $(bc <<< "$(top -b -n1 | grep ^Cpu | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | awk -F% '{print $1}') >= 100") -eq 1 ]] ; then echo '...'; 
fi
```

This is for CPU. Can anybody explain me what does the awk in this example? And how would be awk for RAM?

Comment: Why would anyone parse the output of `top` to get a system load instead of just using `uptime`?

Comment: That's a horribly convoluted script. I would recommend against using this as the starting point for a bigger script. Go with @William's suggestion and find an example which parses `uptime` instead, or better yet read the `/proc` filesystem directly if you are on a platform which provides that.

Comment: I unfortunelly don't have time for doing this sctipt again. Linux is not my forte.

Answer (score 1):

The first awk invocation will print the second token on any line, where tokens are separated by a colon or a space.

The second will print the first token in any line where the tokens are separated by a percent sign (%).

To get the used memory on a Linux system:

```
free | awk '/Mem:/ {print $3;}'
```

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, and what about RAM? It will be the same?

Comment: Are you asking if awk uses a lot of memory? No, it doesn't.

Comment: No, I need to know, if this script for CPU is the same for RAM.

Comment: No it will not be the same.  Which RAM statistic do you need?

Comment: I need to know how much the RAM is used

Comment: I edited the answer with a script command to get the used memory.  The number printed is how many K of memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very fragile script based upon what looks like an old version of **top**.  It is very very easy to inspect this piece of script though - so, let's go through it.  We start with the following:

```
top -b -n1
```

Which (reading the manual for **top**) places **top** into batch mode (meaning that instead of wanting to play interactively with **top**, we want to send output to another command) and outputs with 1 iteration.  That will get us output like the following:

```
$ top -b -n1
top - 10:48:33 up 1 day, 22:51,  3 users,  load average: 1.21, 1.27, 1.03
Tasks: 262 total,   2 running, 260 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.5 us,  5.2 sy, 11.3 ni, 67.3 id,  1.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8124692 total,  6722112 used,  1402580 free,   384188 buffers
KiB Swap:  4143100 total,   430656 used,  3712444 free.  2909664 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
11012 user1     20   0  426412  14436   5740 R  97.1  0.2  19:27.98 dleyna-renderer
 4579 root      20   0  286480 152924  31152 S  13.0  1.9  24:15.49 Xorg
    1 root      20   0  185288   4892   3352 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.52 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.77 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:32.00 rcu_sched
```

When we pipe this to **grep** *^Cpu* ... well it looks like this is where we discover some breakage that indicates that the version of **top** that we are using in this answer may be different in output from the version the original script expected.  It looks like the intent is to match on *^%Cpu* instead.  Here is the corrected piece:

```
$ top -b -n1 | grep ^%Cpu
%Cpu(s): 14.6 us,  5.2 sy, 11.2 ni, 67.3 id,  1.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
```

The next piece of the pipe is to just get rid of the *'%Cpu(s): '* piece:

```
$ top -b -n1 | grep ^%Cpu | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
15.1 us,  5.0 sy, 10.8 ni, 67.4 id,  1.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
```

And then the next piece... **awk** *-F% '{print $1}'* -- doesn't make sense again for this answer's version of **top**, as the script is looking to print what's to the left of a *%* sign -- and there is no *%* in our output.  So... we are left wondering where we need to go from here.

From the rest of the script... the result of the pipeline is compared to 100... so, I assume the version of **top** that the script was meant to parse had a percentage of CPU utilization total in the first column... in our version of **top** output is all broken out with much more granularity.  Here is the breakdown for the immediately preceding output:

```
 15.1% -- spent in normal priority user/applications
  5.0% -- spent in system/kernel
 10.8% -- spent in low priority batch or daemon jobs
 67.4% -- spent "idle"
  1.6% -- spent waiting for I/O to complete
  0.0% -- spent in servicing HW interrupts
  0.1% -- spent in servicing software interrupts
  0.0% -- spent stolen by another VM running on the HW
------------------------------------------------------
100.0% -- Total
```

... So, on modern Linux systems, **top** provides a lot more information, and maybe we need to look at the problem differently.  In this case, we could look at (idle * 10) as the metric -- as in shell, we only have integer math and comparison available to us.  So, we will adjust the script a little... and while we are at it, let's get rid of the **grep** in the pipeline as that can just as easily be done by **awk** as well:

```
$ top -b -n1 | awk -F, '/^%Cpu/ {print $4}'
 67.8 id
```

Now let's adjust it so that it gives us just the idle value multiplied by 10:

```
$ top -b -n1 | awk -F, '/^%Cpu/ { sub(/id/,"",$4); print $4*10 }'
678
```

Ok, the next part of the original script uses **bc** to see if we are 100% utilized.  As we now are looking at idle rather than utilization, we want the opposite of the original script.  Also, we don't need the complication of **bc** now that the output is scaled to integer.  Let's just use shell in our comparison?

```
$ if [ $(top -b -n1 | awk -F, '/^%Cpu/ { sub(/id/,"",$4); print $4*10 }') -le 0 ]; then echo '...'; fi
```

And that is it.

This answer was all to show how the code works -- how to interpret and parse the output of **top** through a pipeline, how to go about the task of figuring out what a piece of script does, and how to go about repairing a fragile/broken script.  However, the original script is not only fragile but is pretty much broken by design. The metric we use to detect an overloaded system is more like the "load average" that is found at the first line of the output of the **top** command, or even better that can be parsed from the output of the **uptime** command.

A way to find out overload may be to look at load average divided by number of cpu's.  Number of cpu's can be found easily parsing /proc/cpuinfo:

```
$ grep ^processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
4
```

Here is one example where 400% load over 15 minutes is considered to be the continuous loading threshold:

```
load=$(uptime | awk -F, '{ print $(NF) * 1.0 }')
proc=$(grep ^processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)
plod=$(awk "BEGIN { x = 100 * $load / $proc; print int(x) + int(x+x)%2 }")

if [ $plod -gt 400 ]; then echo '...'; fi
```

note: *int(x) + int(x+x)%2* is a rounding function

For the amount of free memory on the system, I like ***schtever***'s answer -- except that I would use column 4 rather than column 3 and check that for low memory.